# Android error on parse json when array key have more length

Tags: php, android

i'm trying to parse json array response from server. for example i can simply parse this response :

```
echo json_encode(['result' => 0,'h'=>1,'m'=>2]);
```

but for parse this json format:

```
echo json_encode(['result' => 0,'hour'=>1,'minute'=>2]);
```

i get this error:

```
 E/Response:: {"result":0,"hour":"1","minute":"35"}
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: pishguy.ir.asrebidree, PID: 6322
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: س
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
```

My code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String result = jsonObject.getString("result");

if (result.equals("0")) {
    String hore = jsonObject.getString("hour");
    String minute = jsonObject.getString("minute");
}
```

**UPDATED**

problem is `hour` and `minute` words, not `result` key in json array. after change `hour` and `minute` to `h` and `m` problem solved

Comment: value of "result" key is int not the string

Answer (score 2):

Your `result` is contian `int` value...try this

```
int result = jsonObject.getInt("result");
```