# Cannot get value of JSONArray without JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I get a JSON array from server. If the process is successful, it gives output as such:

```
{
    trainingset: [{
        id: "27",
        trainingID: "94",
        studentID: "4",
        trainingsetCreateTime: "1464028658",
        trainingsetFinishTime: "2018/05/10"
    }],
    success_trainingset: 1,
    trainingobject: [{
        trainingobjectID: "1165",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "1",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "69",
        trainingobjectOne: "69",
        trainingobjectTwo: "131",
        trainingobjectThree: null,
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1166",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "1",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "120",
        trainingobjectOne: "120",
        trainingobjectTwo: "129",
        trainingobjectThree: null,
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1167",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "1",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "128",
        trainingobjectOne: "64",
        trainingobjectTwo: "128",
        trainingobjectThree: null,
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1168",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "2",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "63",
        trainingobjectOne: "63",
        trainingobjectTwo: "129",
        trainingobjectThree: "132",
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1169",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "2",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "111",
        trainingobjectOne: "60",
        trainingobjectTwo: "111",
        trainingobjectThree: "130",
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1170",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "2",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "129",
        trainingobjectOne: "111",
        trainingobjectTwo: "129",
        trainingobjectThree: "132",
        trainingobjectFour: null,
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1171",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "3",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "69",
        trainingobjectOne: "69",
        trainingobjectTwo: "112",
        trainingobjectThree: "129",
        trainingobjectFour: "132",
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1172",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "3",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "112",
        trainingobjectOne: "63",
        trainingobjectTwo: "112",
        trainingobjectThree: "130",
        trainingobjectFour: "131",
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1173",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "3",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "129",
        trainingobjectOne: "65",
        trainingobjectTwo: "118",
        trainingobjectThree: "129",
        trainingobjectFour: "132",
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }, {
        trainingobjectID: "1174",
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingobjectLevel: "3",
        trainingobjectAnswer: "131",
        trainingobjectOne: "68",
        trainingobjectTwo: "120",
        trainingobjectThree: "130",
        trainingobjectFour: "131",
        trainingobjectFive: null
    }],
    success_trainingobject: 1,
    training: [{
        trainingID: "94",
        trainingEvaluation: "6",
        trainingAim: "Şekil Eğitimi",
        trainingHood: "test için update",
        trainingExplanation: "test içinıpdate",
        behaviorID: "1",
        trainingTotalQuestion: "10",
        trainingOK: "1",
        trainingCreateTime: "1464028529"
    }],
    success_training: 1,
    objectobject: [{
        objectID: "191",
        objectName: "Yıldız",
        objectImage: "4564-89.png",
        objectNumber: "1",
        shapeID: "11",
        colorID: "18",
        createTime: "1460857130",
    }],
    success_object: 1,
    shape: [{
        shapeID: "11",
        shapeName: "Yıldız"
    }],
    success_shape: 1,
    color: [{
        colorID: "18",
        colorName: "Yeşil"
    }],
    success_color: 1
}
```

and some other elements like that and each one has success.

If success_trainingset is not 1, the server wont get all data so i need to check `success_trainingset:` . If it is not succesful, the output is only:

```
{
    success_trainingset: 0,
    message: "No trainingset found"
}
```

I tried all the methods of JSON but did not work.

```
try {
    jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);//result is string coming from server
}
```

This doesn't work, studio gives red

```
jsonObj.getJSONObject("success_trainingset").toString());
```

Also for this:

```
jsonObj.getJSONArray("success_trainingset").getJSONObject(0));
```

Also adding `toString()` is still keeping red.

The error is:

> cannot resolve method java.lang.string

I searched for it but find posts with different problems i.e. [Can't Resolve fromJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244619/cant-resolve-fromjson)

Is my JSON wrong formatted?

```
I need to check like that:

if (....get("success_trainingset") == 1) { // Or equals
    // Get all
} else {
    // Give error
}
```

Comment: Because `success_trainingset` in `int` and you are passing it as `object` check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33034370/2553431) for how to parse `int`

Comment: did above link helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Using org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject

after you've instantiated JSONObject try using get

`boolean success = new JSONObject(result).get("success_trainingset").toString().equals("1");`